# Improve bat script

Tags: windows, batch-file, script

I'm try to improving this and make it looks better. I have two issues

1. When I run as administrator the file that I need won't copy in the user profile (I just run as admin to run the .bat script.
2. When I open the software I need it to close the process and reopen it again, but the script run but commands without waiting the first one to be finished.

```
:: ---Don't print commands
@echo off
 
:: ---Close AnyConnect
taskkill /F /IM vpnagent.exe /IM vpnui.exe
 
:: ----Add the file.xml" file to location
xcopy %~dp0"file.xml" "C:\ProgramData\location\" /S /Q /Y /F
 
:: ----Print a wait notification
echo Installation in progress...
echo Please wait, may take a while
 
:: -----Install "software.exe"
%~dp0software /Silent
 
:: ----Open software
start /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Location" test.exe
Pause

:: ----Close sofware
taskkill /F /IM software.exe

:: ----Copy the "Test" and "Test2" to "C:\Users\[[userid]\AppData\Roaming\location\"
xcopy %~dp0"test.xml" "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Location\" /S /Q /Y /F
xcopy %~dp0"test2.xml" "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Location\" /S /Q /Y /F

:: ----Reopen software
start /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Location" test.exe

:: ----Finish the process
exit
```

Answer (score -2):

The [start](https://www.windows-commandline.com/cmd-start-command/) opens a new window, which then runs "concurrently" with the batch file.

- Don't use start, instead change drive and directory to your starting directory
- And just run the command.

Or use the `WAIT option` - from the help on START

> WAIT        Start application and wait for it to terminate.

Comment: Correct. If you want to avoid `start`'s concurreny, use `start /WAIT`